# Cómo crear DTO correctamente en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Voy a proceder a crear la parte del "Model" de mi arquitectura MVVM en Swift. Y para ello voy a crear los DTO de cada componente/elemento de mi aplicación. 
Nunca lo había hecho antes así que si meto la pata en algún concepto espero que me corrijan.

Por ejemplo tengo un componente que muestra un listado de amigos, con su nombre y sus apellidos.
Aquí, ¿tendría que realizar dos DTO? Me explico:

- Uno para cada amigo, un struct "Amigo":

  ```
  struct Amigo {
      var nombre: String,
      var apellidos: String
  }
  ```
- Y uno para el listado de amigos:

  ```
  struct listadoAmigos {
      var amigos: [Amigo]
  }
  ```

Y, ¿cómo los conectaría luego con la parte lógica en el viewmodel y los utilizaría?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues para empezar, te aconsejo utilizar el protocolo Decodable para el objeto DTO, para que puedas obtener los datos de tu JSON hay mucha info sobre este tipo de decodeo que es muy simple y es muy buena, y pues necesitas crear un DTO de Lista de amigos este objeto si viene en un data en el json pues necesitas crear también ese objeto, por ejemplo... digamos que estamos recibiendo nuestro objeto de la siguiente manera:

{ 
   "status": "Ok",
   "statusCode": 200
   "data": [ 
     { 
        "name": "Albert",
        "lastName": "Einstein"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fiodor",
        "lastName": "Dostoyevski"
        "birthday": "11/11/1821"
      }
     ]
}

nuestro DTO lo que hará es obtener los datos de nuestro json y luego llenarlos en nuestra estructura para mostrarlos en el view entonces creamos un método para llenarlo o pasarlo a nuestra estructura "Amigos"

```
 struct DataFriends: Decodable {
      let data: [DTOFriends]

      /// una función un poco tosca pero para que se comprenda un poco
      func fromDTO(dtoFriends: [DTOFriends]) -> [Friends] {
        let addFriends = [Friends]()
        friends.forEach { (friends) in 
             let new = Friend(name: friends.name, lastName: friends.lastName, birthdate: friends.birthdate)
             addfriends.append(new)
        } 
        return addFriends
      }
 } 

 struct DTOFriends: Decodable {
     let name: String
     let lastName: String
     let birthdate: String?
 }

 struct Friends {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
    let birthdate: String
 }
```

por que dos estructuras casi iguales?? el DTO solamente nos da la data de nuestro web service, o backend, y va estar tratando cualquier cambio que ocurra dentro de lo que recibimos, así solamente damos de alta algún dato que cambie o que este "diferente o falte", por ejemplo el birthdate que en el primer caso esta ausente, y por eso lo colocamos como opcional, y en la estructura Friends, Siempre estará los datos que necesitemos para usarlos en nuestro ViewModel.

El viewModel le puedes inyectar directamente el data con un Init(friends: [Friends]) "esto si usas una de las tres formas de Dependency Injection", o crear la petición en el mismo viewModel y llenar los datos que necesitas, como gustes o como lo veas necesario. pero en esencia el DTO es para tratar y mantener de forma flexible los datos que recibimos del backend, si hay algún cambio el DTO es el encargado de recibir esos datos, si truena por que cambio un dato solo es ajustar el DTO y listo, mas adelante puedes ajustar las estructuras que los usan para llenar los datos, ahora por ejemplo nuestro viewModel podría ser así:

```
 class MyViewModel {
    private var friends: [Friends]

    init(friends: [Friends]) {       // también puedes evitar el init y simplemente creas un método para obtener los datos de backend
       self.friends = friends
 }

     func getFriends() {
  /// ALAMOFIRE... URLSESSION para la petición y llenar el array friends
      }
 }
```

ahora con el init en tu ViewController puedes inicializar el viewModel por ejemplo:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var myViewModel: MyViewModel

     viewdidload .... etc

     init(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
         self.viewmodel = viewModel
         super.init(nib: nil.....ect)
      }
      required init... etc
    }
```

esto en caso de que ya tengas los datos de Friends para mandar llamar el viewController de otro..  por ejemplo digamos que lo iniciarías usando el dto directamente... en una petición que al dar success vas a ese Controller....

```
  class someController: UIViewController {

   /// func donde optengo datos
   func getData() {
      //request.... y digamos que usas el decode y obtienes tu dtoObject de un optional
      guard let responseDTO = response else { return }
      let controller = ViewController(viewModel: MyViewModel(friends: responseDTO.fromDTO())
       // con push para navigation
      navigationController.pushToViewController(controller, animated: true)
   }
  }
```

si es un poco engorroso, y hay diferentes métodos para llenar los datos, este es solo un ejemplo pequeño que quizá te pueda servir como guía de lo que hace un DTO. y como puedes pasar los datos a tu vieModel, ya sea directamente en el o desde otra clase.